# Access to the path '/dev/shm/AzureFunctions' is denied. Operation not permitted. while running a function on a Mac

Tags: debugging, azure-functions

When I try use debug on an Azure function, I get this error:

```
[2021-10-09T15:50:50.996Z] Cannot create directory for shared memory
usage: /dev/shm/AzureFunctions 
[2021-10-09T15:50:50.996Z]
System.IO.FileSystem: Access to the path '/dev/shm/AzureFunctions' is
denied. Operation not permitted.
```

I already downgraded NodeJS to v13.

How can I solve this issue on a Mac?

Comment: Please post the solution when you have found it?